# What does X do in Integer.parseInt(..,X)?

Tags: java, parseint

I'm trying to get Characters from decimal and hex value.

I tried this code.

```
(char) Integer.parseInt("AE",16)
```

It displayed a hexadecimal character, namely (R).

Then I tried

```
(char) Integer.parseInt("65283",32)
```

That displayed a east asian character, perhaps Chinese.

Can Anyone please explain me, what these numbers (16,32) stand for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a full example of what you're expecting?

Comment: I am trying get all the 65 333 Unicode characters.

Comment: How about simply casting to (char)

Comment: Please put the focused question in the title. If you want to treat "65283" as 65283, simply supply 10 (decimal) for the radix or omit it (as it will default to 10)

Comment: @pst what will anyone achive by passing 10 for decimal value ?

Comment: @AmitD To parse the string as decimal. Equivalent to emitting the radix, but is useful to see symmetry and could be useful where the radix is not constant, perhaps. While in this case it is likely better to just write `(char)65283`, it is important to keep in mind that `(char)"65283"` and `(char)userInputString` are both invalid.

Comment: What part of the Javadoc didn't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Integer.parseInt("AE",16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

16, 32 represent radix

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument

and

> The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix

Comment: so radix 16 is hexadecimal. What are values I can set in?

Comment: @Freetalk13: read the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29